# How to get meta data from custom category name

Tags: posts, customization

I want to get meta data by custom post type category name.

Right now i am getting all meta data but i want specific for each category

```
$partSql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'prd_part_no'", ARRAY_A);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get_post_meta function in wordpress to achieve this, that's a link [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to it in the wordpress codex.

Comment: Thank you But i want get post meta by category.

Right now i am getting all post meta, but i want to display who are available in category.

Comment: You can get post meta by category by using this function 
<?php get_metadata($meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key, $single)  ?>
For more details refer this link  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata